# Dexie - Cannot add version when database is open

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, indexeddb, dexie

I am using [Dexie.js](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js) and sometimes I receive the error "Cannot add version when database is open" when trying to access the database.

Is there a best practice to deal with this error? Do I need to close the database in that case and try to reopen it?

My code is this (written in CoffeeScript):

```
  @db = new Dexie @db_name
  @db.version db_version
  .stores stores
  .upgrade (transaction) =>
    console.warn 'Database upgrade needed'

  @db.open()
  .then ->
    console.log 'Storage initialized'
  .catch (error) ->
    console.error error.message, error
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in **Dexie 1.3.2** by keeping a reference to the version instance and surrounding the assignment for it with a try-catch-block:

```
try
  version_instance = @db.version db_version
catch error
  if error.message is 'Cannot add version when database is open'
    @db.close()
    version_instance = @db.version db_version
```